# Which of the browser is best for development purpose? Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: browser

Just want to know what browser you guys are using mostly for dev purpose from this listed - Chrome or Firefox?

Which of the browser is safe too?

Thanks

Comment: Most of the new versions of browsers have Developer tools. To use developer tools, right-click on the page and choose `Inspect`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. Which is more convenient? Firefox or Chrome?